# Changing a program while it is running

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

Not sure if this is an emacs-SLIME issue or a CL issue or SBCL issue.

I've heard it said that the interactive nature of Lisp allows for changing a program while the program is running. Not knowing the specifics of what is meant by this, I tried the following, placing this in a separate file:

```
(defparameter repl-test-var 5)
(defun repl-test ()
  (format t "repl-test-var is: ~a" repl-test-var)
  (fresh-line)
  (when (not (equal (read-line) "quit"))
    (repl-test)))
```

Then I compile and run `(repl-test)` and every time I press enter, I see the number `5`.

Without typing `quit` at the REPL, I go back to my file and change the `5` to a `6` and compile again. Back at the REPL, pressing Enter still shows the `5`. If I type `quit` and then run `(repl-test)` again, now I see the `6`.

I have also tried loading as well as a combination of compile followed by loading using the SLIME shortcuts and they also have no effect until after I quit the running program and then start it again.

Is what I am trying to do either not possible or requiring another step in the code?

I realize it is a trivial example, but in more complex scenarios I may wish to do this.

Comment: Recompiling the file doesn't load it into the running Lisp environment.

Comment: @Barmar I have also tried loading as well as a combination of compile followed by loading using the SLIME shortcuts and they also have no effect until after I quit the running program and then start it again.

Comment: Which Lisp are you running underneath? How are you running it? Perhaps enough additional scope to warrant a separate question...? "How do I run <implementation> interactively?"

Comment: @tripleee updated question, I'm using SBCL. As for "how" i'm running it; just from a REPL. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I gave this some more thought in the meantime; see updated answer.

Comment: @OpenLearner Your sample runs as you desire in my SLIME + SBCL, by recompiling & reloading with the C-c C-c or C-c C-k slime defaults. When I do that slime prints a compilation message mixed in with the test's output -- do you get the same mixed output or does the compilation print only after you quit from repl-test?

Comment: @m-n interesting. I am not getting that behavior, with those SLIME SBCL key combos.

Comment: One thing that the comments so far haven't mentioned yet is how threading might affect this.  If it's the case that special variables have a binding per thread, then if the compilation and loading occurs in a different thread than the one that your function is running in, you might not see the change… This is just a thought;  I'm not sure whether it's what you're seeing.

Comment: @OpenLearner Like Joshua I also suspect a threading issue, but a different threading issue. Is :sb-thread a member of \*features\*? My hypothesis is that if you have a single threaded SBCL, loading changes might be blocked by your loop.

Comment: @m-n no, `sb-thread` is not shown in *features* should it be? if it should, how to add it?

Comment: My first guess would be that you only recompiled the `defun`, not the `defparameter` form.

Comment: @Svante no but good guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code is not being reloaded while the REPL is busy because your SBCL image is single threaded. You can determine that your SBCL is single threaded by checking that :sb-thread is not present in *features*. Threaded vs unthreaded is determined when SBCL itself is compiled, so to get the behavior you desire you will need to either acquire an SBCL binary with threads enabled or compile SBCL with threads enabled.

A lack of threads can get in the way of some benefits of interactive development (as in your test, or if you want to develop a web program that has a server component running in the same image) but it still leaves some benefits open. Some handy aspects of interactive development that don't require your program to be actively "doing" anything for you to enjoy them include that you only have to reload the parts of your program that you changed, that this reloading does not cause the program to dump the data it has loaded (as a restart might), and that the REPL can be used as a handy window into your program's state and behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When functions are replaced in Lisp it doesn't mean "self-modifying code".

If a function is being executed in Lisp, the instruction pointer holds a reference to the function, and so the function continues to be a live object that cannot be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

When you redefine a function, what that means is that a new function object is associated with the name. When the function is called by name, the new function is used.

However, existing calls to the function which are in progress will continue to use the old function (which is not attached to the symbol any more). When the last thread stops executing that function, it will become garbage.

This is very similar to the "last close", in Unix, on an open file that has been deleted from the directory structure.

The issue shows up not only with multiple threads, but with simple recursion. If the function that is executing **itself** triggers the redefinition, then the function will continue with the old body. Moreover, Lisp allows the self-calls in recursive functions to avoid going through the name binding, but use a direct mechanism. If a recursive function redefines itself, the recursive calls still to be made in the same invocation may keep going to the same body.

More generally, Common Lisp allows compilers to generate efficient calls among functions that are in the same file. So you normally have to think of replacement of running code as being at the module level rather than individual function level. If functions A and B are in the same module, and A calls B,  then if you merely replace B without replacing A, A may continue calling the old B (because B was inlined into A, or because A doesn't go through the symbol, but uses a more direct address for B). You can declare functions `notinline` to suppress this.

CL has a number of features that provide a lot of control over the semantics of compilation and loading, so you can get the precise behaviors you need in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs itself is a magnificent example of this. Change a function's definition (probably not something crucial like `car` or `self-insert-command`! :-) and watch its behavior change. See also in particular the [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) facility of Emacs.

A compiled Lisp program, by definition, is not running an interactive REPL, though, so does not expose this behavior out of the box.

The problem with your example code is similar. It ties up the REPL, so there is no easy way to change the program's environment while it's running.

What makes Lisp so versatile (albeit not unique) is that (a) it gives you `eval`; (b) it's very easy to write your own REPL on top of it; and (c) the best ones also offer documentation and/or hooks for modifying and extending their built-in REPL.

A more useful example program would `eval` some input (keyboard input? Disk file? Authenticated download?) while it continues to run.

Outside of the "secret sauce" that is `eval`, it  is easy to find examples of programs which allow you to, say, upgrade a plug-in while the program continues to run compiled code, but Lisp does not provide any special facility for this -- the program needs to be built to support this.

Comment: Suppose I do not compile, and simply `load` the program into the REPL, it still does not update the program's behavior while it is running.

Comment: Erlang allegedly allows you to switch running components at will, but I cannot provide any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the running program, you have to find a way to interact with the running lisp image while your program is running.  This can be done using multithreading, or by invocing the debugger.

To use multi-threading: Try starting the function like this:

```
(defparameter *thread* (sb-thread:make-thread #'repl-test))
```

If using `emacs` + `slime`: Test the function in the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer, and change it in the `*slime-repl sbcl*` buffer.

Another test program that demonstrates changing a running program is this:

```
(defun update (i) 
   (+ i 1))

(defun hotpatch-test ()
       (loop for i = 0 then (update i) do
       (format t "~&i = ~d~%" i)
       (fresh-line)
       (sleep 5)))
```

Start it with

```
(defparameter *thread* (sb-thread:make-thread #'hotpatch-test))
```

Observe the numbers being printed, then change the definition of `update` *e.g.* like

```
(defun update (i)
   (+ i 2))
```

and see how the sequence of numbers output changes.

Finally, the thread may be killed with

```
(sb-thread:terminate-thread *thread*)
```

**Update:**

Another way to update the running program, without using multiprocessing, is to interupt the program with `C-c` (or `C-c C-c` in slime), load/enter new code while in the debugger, and then chose the `continue` restart in order to continue running the program from where it was interupted.

Comment: when i try starting the thread on my SLIME with SBCL, I get this error from the REPL: `Not supported in unithread builds.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]`

Comment: @OpenLearner Then your SBCL is built without threading support.  See my updated answer on how to update a running program using the debugger instead of multithreading.