# Recompile doesn't correct typo in function call

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I've been seeing this a lot lately and am not sure if it is an SBCL issue, an Emacs problem, a SLIME problem, or my own understanding of what it means to "compile" a lisp file.

I will have a function, say this:

`(defun some-function (x) (call-this-funcshun))`

I will compile and run this, and I'll get an error that my function `call-this-funcshun` is not defined. Then I realize that is because there is a typo. So change it:

`(defun some-function (x) (call-this-function))`

In Emacs, I recompile the entire file with Control-C Control-K (Emacs saves automatically before the compile as well). Emacs then reports `Compilation finished.` I move to the REPL. I try it again, type `(some-function whatever)` and I get the same error. I search through the small lisp file and see that `call-this-funcshun` is clearly nowhere in it. Yet I have an error that this function is not defined.

Is there some sort of caching that Emacs or SBCL is doing that causes this to hang around? It's driving me nuts. Worth noting that if I quit SLIME and then launch it again, the issue is resolved. Also worth noting that this does not affect all my code edits, just occasionally.

Comment: Isn't this effectively a duplicate of your recent question [Changing a program while it is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259845/changing-a-program-while-it-is-running) ?

Comment: @phils, no, because the program is not running when I make a change. That other question was about a function currently running and looping in the REPL while you recompile. I doubt very much it is related.

Comment: is your file reloaded automatically? Have you tried reloading the recompiled file manually?

Comment: @WillNess The Control CK combo (which is "compile and load") nearly always does what I'd expect: compiles and any changes to any functions are immediately there when I run them again at REPL. But on occasion it does not, as per the above. What is the typical workflow; does one usually compile and then separately load in REPL via `load` function?

Comment: @OpenLearner I've opened emacs with slime and sbcl repl in *inferior-lisp* and defined a function (defun tstfun (x) (printas 3)) and hit ctrl+c ctrl+k and got 2 warnings: 1) printas is not defined and 2) x is unused. Then I changed in to (defun tstfun (x) (print 3)) and hit ctrl+c ctrl+k, then hit ctrl+x b to switch to *inferior-lisp* and call (tstfun 2) and lisp printed "3". Is this the same you are trying to do? Or I didn't understand your question?

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious that's correct. Most of the time, it works, but sometimes new changes are not recognized unless I restart slime. the other difference for me is that I am using the SLIME REPL, not the inferior lisp buffer.

Comment: @OpenLearner This never happend to me, but I don't use ctrl+c ctrl+k. I usually use crtl+c ctrl+c - compile current top level form to compile the function where I made some changes. (actually there should be no difference, because Cc Cc just created a temporary fasl). And use "slime-load-file" to load all stuff from recently open lisp file. So you can try to use ctrl+c ctrl+c next time this happens and any result will be interesting.

Comment: As frustrating as this is, note that "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself."  Now, this isn't a code problem so much as an IDE issue, so it's not code that would reproduce it, but a sequence of actions.  I just created a file with a `call-this-function` and `some-function` as you've described, compiled and loaded (C&L), got the expected error, modified the file, C&Led again, and everything was fine.  Do you have a reliable way of reproducing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the file is not loaded for some reason.

I would set `*load-verbose*` to `T` and watch that `LOAD` actually gets called.
Setting `*load-print*` to `T` would then also cause the printing of information about definitions loaded.

Comment: I think this is excellent advice (and probably necessary, if the problem is to be solved), but would probably be better as a comment, since it doesn't (yet, anyway) actually have an answer to the @OpenLearner's particular problem.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: I don't think it is good to bury **advice** in comments, if it targets the problem and is useful for others. The advice is hard to find there, just look at the comments for this question. There are comments which are about the question, and then comment discussions - this lacks structure.
Also: some problems don't have a direct answer, but can be solved by pointing to the right tools.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I understand your point, but this where the "spirit" of the site tends to win over the "letter" and I agree with Mr. Joswig.

Comment: @RainerJoswig That's just it though, this _is_ very good advice, and will hopefully lead OpenLearner to find the solution, but if _someone else_ has this same problem, they come here and find an accepted answer that doesn't actually solve their problem;  it just points them to a debugging technique and makes them cross their fingers that they're as lucky as OpenLearner in their debugging attempts. It's very important debugging information, and should be included in an answer, but on its own it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @OpenLearner I think that this information needs to be included in any answer to this question;  it's very good information, and anyone running into this problem in the future should try this technique.  The community has actually spoken about this kind of issue (answers that don't actually answer the question, but may still provide useful information), e.g., in [Up- and Down- voting on non-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209618/225437).  The consensus seems to be in favor of converting those kinds of "answers" to comments.

Comment: @OpenLearner Since you have accepted this answer though, can you tell use what the actual problem ended up being?  If someone else comes across this problem in their emacs/SLIME setup, what do they need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two conditions that can lead to behavior that looks like what you saw:

1. When the symbol in the file is not the same as the symbol at the REPL. The symbol's name is only a shorthand for identifying the symbol, and the same shorthand can identify **different** symbols based on which package you use it in. There are some ways to be surprised about which symbol you are referring to, so it can be worth checking with SYMBOL-PACKAGE even when you are pretty sure that they are the same.
2. When the buffer isn't saved. I'm not sure how C-c C-k deals with this now (because I edited it to auto-save for me), but in general compiling and loading tools tend to work from the *file* not the *buffer*.